# Saving an image to a folder in php

Tags: php

What I tried :

```
   $url = str_replace(' ', '%20', trim($url));
    $percent = 1.0; 
    $imagethumbsize = 200;
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($url);
    $new_width = $width * $percent;
    $new_height = $height * $percent;


    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($imagethumbsize , $imagethumbsize);  
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($url);

    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, -($new_width/2) + ($imagethumbsize/2), -($new_height/2) + ($imagethumbsize/2), 0, 0, $new_width , $new_width , $width, $height);
    $hel=imagejpeg($image_p,"E:".DS."xampp".DS."htdocs".DS."opg-uat".DS."img".DS."c".DS , 100);
```

The Error I get : "This image can not be saved because it contains error "
Somebody help pls.

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
if($hel)
    echo 'Image saved';
```

from your code. It's an image but you are writing textual content onto it.

Comment: I did . Not getting any error , But the image is not getting saved. HELP

Comment: Try replacing your `imagejpeg()` in the last line with `imagejpeg($image_p, 'simpletext.jpg');`

Answer (score 0):

Try to log at error.log or put this at the top of your php file:

`error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

it will show all errors.